# An English Song/Poetry With Differrent Grammatic Structure

Tags: grammar, poetry

The other day, I have watched the movie King Arthur Legend of the Sword and, in it, there was an energizer song that includes some words and structure with which I am not familiar. Here are the lyrics:

> Young man came from hunting faint, tired and weary
>
> What does ail my Lord, my dearie?
>
> Oh, brother dear, let my bed be made
>
> For I feel the gripe of the woody nightshade
>
> Men need a man would die as soon
>
> Out of the light of a mage's moon
>
> But it's not by bone, but yet by blade
>
> Can break the magic that the devil made
>
> And it's not my fire, but was forged in flame
>
> Can drown the sorrows of a huntsman's pain

Firstly, I haven't understood the bold sentence (for I feel...). Because woody nightshade is a species of a plant. Why it causes gripe of King who hunted.

Secondly, I haven't understood "But it's not bone, not yet blade". Where is "it" refer to? and "what is meant by "by bone".

Finally, I haven't understood who is the subject of "can"s. Please help me to understand.

By the way, here is the link of the song:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGnfFW-vyzU&ab_channel=WaterTowerMusic

Thank you so much.

Comment: This song is written in the style of a folk song, so you wouldn't expect it to follow the strict rules of grammar. [Woody nightshade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_dulcamara) is a poisonous plant.

Comment: The subject of the first 'can' is on the previous line: *it's not by bone, but yet by blade*, where the **it** refers to breaking the magic in the next line. So those two lines mean "The devils' magic can't be broken by bone, but by blade." I don't know what 'bone' means, but perhaps it means that bone weapons are primitive, whereas a blade is 'modern' and powerful.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for answering. I understand the lines in terms of meaning thanks to your explanation. But, I think, the lines should rethink again in terms of grammar. Because, If the subject of "can" was  "it" in the first line there wouldn't be "is" after "it". Because it is impossible to say that "it is can break the magic that the devil made". I think there should be another thing. But I can't found it.

Comment: Yes I know, it's not ordinary text. But I want to understand the grammar and connections. Therefore I will be able to understand other poems which I'll see in the future by comparing this. Moreover, I highly defend that all text can explain according to grammar. It is just about seeing and noticing the details.

Comment: To add to @KateBunting comment _gripe_ is a pain in the stomach or bowels. In this case presumably caused by consuming a poisonous plant.

Comment: "It is not by a bone, but by a blade that the magic made by the devil can be broken." _Can break_ is not grammatical, but, as I said, it's a folk song.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you so much. By your analysis, I finally became closer to understand it exactly. But it seems to me that "by" is used here in a different way. Because if there "by" hadn't been in the sentence, it might have been more meaningful. Because the structure would have been like that: "But it's not a bone, but yet a blade that can break the magic that the devil made". So I think the usage of "by" is different as if it is put only for ryhme.